# Invalid conversion from runtime type String to SOBJECT:

Tags: visualforce, map, fieldsets

I have create a filed set on a custom object and trying to display the filed set to a VF page from apex code. This much is working fine but when i try to loop through the map in which the value is entered i am getting an error Invalid conversion from runtime type String to SOBJECT:. My code :

```
 public Candidates__c ca_Insert {get; set;} // For inserting Candidates records 
public blob Attach {get;set;}  // For attaching Resume to the specific record
public String fileName {get; set;}
public Attachment a {get; set;}
public Id jobID {get; set;}// To get the ID from URL
public Boolean isSaved{get; set;}// To know is saved successfully
public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> candidateFields{get; set;}
public map<string, Candidates__c> fieldMap {get; set;}
public map<string, string> fieldMap_api {get; set;}
public Candidates__c field_disp {get;set;}


public ctrl_Candidate_Site(){    
    ca_Insert = new Candidates__c(); 
    //ca_Insert = (Candidates__c)stdController.getRecord(); // getting records from VF page 
    jobID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('jobId'); // Getting the jobId from URL   
    candidateFields = new List<Schema.FieldSetMember> ();
    a = new Attachment();  
    candidateFields = Schema.SObjectType.Candidates__c.fieldSets.getMap().get('CMSR__Candidate').getFields() ;
    system.debug('Fieldset values ' + candidateFields );

    fieldMap = new map<string, Candidates__c>();
    fieldMap_api = new map<string, string>();
    field_disp = new Candidates__c ();  
     for(integer i =0; i < candidateFields.size(); i++ ){
         system.debug('get field field ' + candidateFields[i] );
         system.debug('get field Label ' + candidateFields[i].getLabel() );
         system.debug('get field Required ' + candidateFields[i].getRequired());
         fieldMap.put( candidateFields[i].getLabel(),  field_disp );
         fieldMap_api.put( candidateFields[i].getLabel(),  candidateFields[i].getFieldPath() );
     }
     system.debug('Map fields' + fieldMap);
}


public PageReference SaveResult(){

     system.debug('Value entered in map from Vf page ' + fieldMap); 
     for(string f : fieldMap.keyset()){

         system.debug('map keyset Value ' + f);
         system.debug('map entered Value ' + string.valueof(fieldMap.get(f)));

     }

     return null;
}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page id="Cnd_page1" showHeader="false" controller="ctrl_Candidate_Site" >

<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>

  <style>
    h1{
        font-size:16px;
        padding-left:50px;
        font-family:'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#3366FF;
        line-height:20px;
    }
    .tableStyle{
        padding-left:50px;
        font-size:14px;
        font-family:'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#343434;
    }
    .cm_formCss{
         height:100%;
         margin:auto;
         width:960px;


    }
    .tdStyleFirst{
        height:25px;
        margin-bottom:13px;
        margin-left:2px;
        width:50%;
    }
    .tdStyleSecond{
        height:25px;

    }

</style>


<apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}" >
 <apex:define name="body" > 
    <apex:form id="Cnd_form" >
        <h1>Candidate</h1>
          <table class="tableStyle">              
          <apex:repeat value="{!fieldMap}" var="f"> 

                <tr>



                     <td class="tdStyleFirst"> 
                          <apex:outputText value="{!f}"  />  </td> 
                     <td> <apex:inputText value="{!fieldMap[f]}" />  </td>                         
                </tr>        

          </apex:repeat> 
                  <tr>
                      <td>Attach Resumes</td>
                      <td><apex:inputFile value="{!Attach}" accept="doc, docx, txt, pdf" filesize="1000" filename="{!fileName}"></apex:inputFile> </td>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr>
                      <td></td>                          
                      <td> <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveResult}" value="Submit"/>
                           <apex:commandButton action="{!reset}" value="Reset" /> </td>
                  </tr>

          </table>
    </apex:form>
</apex:define>
```

can anybody guide me how to get it solved.

Comment: Can you post visualforce page of which it is controller?

Comment: have edited the questions.

Comment: Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This line on visualforce page is reason:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!fieldMap[f]}" />
```

`fieldMap` is a `Map` which returns `sObject` type when you pass a key of type `String` and you are referencing it with `<apex:input>` which accepts `String`

Instead of directly assigning sObject `Candidate__c` assign its field value ex:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!fieldMap[f].name}" />
```

Comment: but if i use fieldMap[f].name the fields are coming from filed set so it is dynamic then how can i use static field.

Comment: You can pass field api name directly into custom object instance. Syntax should be {!fieldMap[f][fieldAPIName]} @AnuRaj